# Finding and ranking intervals of data

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

Every time I ride my bike a gather second by second data on a number of metrics. For simplicity, lets pretend that I have a csv file that looks something like:

```
secs, watts,
1,150
2,151
3,149
4,135
.
.
.
7000,160
```

So, every second of my ride has an associated power value, in watts.

I want to know "If I break my ride into N second blocks, which blocks have the realize in the highest average power?"

I am using a pandas dataframe to manage my data, and this is the code I have been using to answer my question:

```
def bestEffort(ride_data,
             metric='watts',
             interval_length=5,
             sort_descending=True):

seconds_in_ride = len(ride_data[metric])

average_interval_list = [[i+1, 
                          np.average(
                             [ride_data[metric][i+j] 
                               for j in range(interval_length)])
                             ] 
                           for i in range(0, 
                                            seconds_in_ride - 
                                                    interval_length)]

average_interval_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=sort_descending)

return average_interval_list
```

Seems simple? Right? Given an index, compute the average value of the interval_length subsequent entries. Keep track of this in a list of the form

```
[[second 1, avg val of metric over the interval starting that second],
 [second 2, avg val of metric over the interval starting that second],
 [second 3, avg val of metric over the interval starting that second],
 .
 .
 .
 [second 7000-interval_length, avg val of metric over the interval starting that second]]
```

Then, I sort the resulting list by the average values. So the first entry is of the form

```
[second_n, avg val of metric over the interval starting in second n]
```

telling me that my strongest effort over the given interval length started at second_n in my workout.

The problem is that if I set "interval_length" to anything higher than 30, this computation takes forever (read: over two minutes on a decent machine). Please, help me find where my code is hitting a bottleneck, this seems like it should be way faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you put your data in a numpy array, say `watts`, you can compute the mean power using convolve:

```
mean_power = np.convolve(watts, np.ones(interval_length)/interval_length, mode='valid')
```

As you can see in [the reference of np.convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html), this function computes a local mean of the first argument, smoothed with a window defined by the second argument. Here we smooth with a "top-hat" function--i.e. an "on/off" function which is constant over an interval of length `interval_length`, and zero otherwise. This is rudimentary but gives a first estimate.

Then the time of your strongest effort is:

```
time_strongest_effort = np.argmax(mean_power)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure-pandas solution using `DataFrame.rolling`. It's slightly slower than the numpy convolution approach by @BenBoulderite, but is a convenient idiom:

```
df.rolling(interval_length).mean().shift(-(interval_length - 1))
```

The `.shift()` is needed to align the rolling-mean values so that the results are aligned to the *left* edge of the rolling window, instead of the default right edge ([docs on DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)).